# Whether the statement make sense

Tags: trigonometry

I am concerned about a question given as ;

In Exercises 152–155, determine whether each
statement makes sense or does not make sense, and explain your
reasoning

[image: The given statement is : Using the equation for simple harmonic motion described in Exercises 133–134, I need to solve a trigonometric equation to determine the ball’s distance from its rest position after 2 seconds.]

And reference of 133-134,

[image]

According to me, we can determine the ball's distance from its rest position after 2 seconds just by substituting $t=2$ in the function $d$. So the statement makes sense, but in the answer it is given it does not make sense. Can any one explain am I correct or why I am wrong.

Comment: Your question itself makes little sense. I suspect you have miscopied or misinterpreted the exercise you have been assigned. If the assignment is to “decide whether the given statement makes sense,” you should very succinctly tell us what “the given statement” is.

Comment: That given  statement is : Using the equation for simple harmonic motion described in Exercises 133–134, I need to solve a trigonometric equation to determine the ball’s distance from its rest position after 2 seconds. And for reference,  i have mentioned what 134-135 exercise was.

Comment: I don’t see how that can possibly be right. You’re supposed to determine whether the English sentence making an assertion of the form “I need to solve…” “makes sense”? This is not a mathematical question. Moreover there is really no relationship of this statement to what is actually said in exercises 133 and 134. Something is wrong in your request or your reading of the assignment.

Comment: Perhaps what you are asking is something like this. “To answer exercises 133 and 134, **is it true or false** that I should determine the ball’s distance after two seconds?” The answer to that question is “false.” To answer 133 and 134, you shouldn’t evaluate $d$ at $t=2$. You should instead find the values of $t$ where $d>2$ and $d<-2$. But notice this has nothing to do with whether a statement “makes sense”; it is simply about truth and falsity. The language you use is very imprecise.

Comment: Now I have pasted the snip of the question.